# How to hide a view when moving through pages with contextual filters?

Tags: views

I'm new at drupal and I´ve been struggling with contextual filters. Here is my situation: I have 2 views in one page. One of them displays an article list which creates a pager and the other view is at the very top of the page displaying only 3 main articles.

What I want is to hide that view (the top one) when the user move through the pages and only display it when is on the first page.

I have read that I could use a contextual filter to get the value of the page from the URL but so far I haven't been able to do it.